# Syntax highlight for footnotes in Vim

Tags: footnotes, vim

I always write my footnotes in LaTeX as

```
Some text.%
\footnote{This is the footnote text.}
Text continued.
```

This way the footnote is always on its own line beginning with `\footnote{` and ending with `}` followed by newline. It should therefore be easily delimitable with a regular expression. I am rather new to Vim and am not really friends with the way regex is implemented in it.

My attempt is to have this in the .vimrc:

```
syntax match footnote "\\\(footnote\|footnotetext\){\zs.+\ze}\r"
highlight link footnote Comment
```

The idea is only to highlight the text within the `\footnote`. Vim does not complain but it does nothing. What am I doing wrong here?

(To have it linked with the `Comment` group is probably not the best idea.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want this in your .vimrc. The correct place to put this is in your after directory. See `:help after-directory`.

One of the last places that vimscript files get loaded from is `~/.vim/after` so here we want to change a bit of syntax highlighting, so we want `~/.vim/after/syntax/`. If that path doesn't exist, create it. Then create a file called `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim`. I'm not sure your regex is correct either, I used the following in `tex.vim` (though there may be a better regex):

```
syntax match footnote "\v\\footnote(text)?\{[^}]+}"
highlight link footnote Comment
```

Using this regex it doesn't matter if the footnote comes in the middle of the text or on it's own line. If for some reason you only want to highlight it if it is on it's own line, you can anchor the regex with:

```
syntax match footnote "\v^\\footnote(text)?\{[^}]+}$"
highlight link footnote Comment
```

You can open the test file and try:

```
:set syntax=tex
```

and you should see the highlighting. This worked for me but I didn't want to have to set the highlighting every time. I had to do a little more because the `tex` format isn't the only script being used for syntax highlighting (at least in my vim). If you open the file you want to check highlighting for, you can use `:scriptnames` to see what was installed. You should see a list of vim files that were loaded. In my list the last two I see are:

```
/home/share/vim/vim73/syntax/plaintex.vim
/home/share/vim/vim73/syntax/initex.vim
```

So I don't actually need `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim` I really need:

```
~/.vim/after/syntax/plaintex.vim
~/.vim/after/syntax/initex.vim
```

One of these has the highlighting for `\footnote` and the other `\footnotetext`. Now if I load a `tex` file and run `:scriptnames`, the last four scripts are:

```
/home/share/vim/vim73/syntax/plaintex.vim
/home/share/vim/vim73/syntax/initex.vim
~/.vim/after/syntax/initex.vim
~/.vim/after/syntax/plaintex.vim
```

Comment: I tried placing the first snippet in the specified file but with no result. Also I didn't understand the last part. Could you expand on it a little?

Comment: @Andreas I added a bit more detail to the file location and using `:scriptnames`, is that what was missing or did you mean something else?

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. I am using MacVim and it loads `/MacVim.app/Contnents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/tex.vim`. Thereafter it loads my `after/syntax/tex.vim`. So it should show up when the `tex` syntax is set, right?

Comment: @Andreas If you can see that your `after/syntax/tex.vim` is being sourced then the file detection sounds like it's working. You can double check your regex by copying the `tex.vim` file to `foo.vim` and then open a new file `test.foo`, make sure your `after/syntax/foo.vim` is sourced and then see if the syntax highlighting works, if not then you have a bad regex. Keep in mind that if the regex includes the closing `}` it won't match until you include the closing brace.

Comment: I did some testing and the pattern `"\v(\\footnote(text)?\{)@<=.+(\}$)@="` in `after/syntax/tex.vim` works for a small testfile, but only after I do `:set syntax=tex`. It does for some reason no not work on the larger file I am currently working on.

Comment: If it only shows up when you `:set syntax=tex` then you might not be loading only the `tex` file to provide the syntax of those two commands.