# Coloring footnote syntax in vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I would like LaTeX footnotes to have a different color in nvim, much like VS Code does it:

[image: footnote syntax coloring in VS Code]

I found [this old question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219772/syntax-highlight-for-footnotes-in-vim), which suggests putting this in after/syntax/tex.vim

```
syntax match footnote "\v\\footnote(text)?\{[^}]+}"
highlight link footnote Comment
```

But the regex pattern only matches simple footnotes that don't contain `\cite[]{}` commands. Has someone figured out how to do more complex syntax highlighting, like in the example screenshot above? I like in particular that the `cite` commands still get their own coloring.

Comment: This appears to go a long way in answering this question:  `syntax match footnote "\v\\footnote\{[^\\]*|(\})@<=[^\\]+(\\)@=|(\})@<=[^\\]*\}"
highlight link footnote Todo`